# How to Pandas fillna by method bfill with first occurence of data for the same ID

Tags: python, pandas

i have a CSV pandas https://www.dropbox.com/s/phnbeklg09ze6t0/test.csv?dl=0

i am trying to fillna with bfill method on column catH based on values of first seen value in column A.
e.g. in row 382, column A ID is 271 with value M, its the first occurence of ID 271 (later occurence may have different values so i couldnt use group by), so previous nan values should be fill with value 'm'

further example if row386, col A has ID 1286, and has value 'b', so row 746, 726, 704, and so on backwards with 1286 should be bfill with value 'b'

anyone know a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Hi Desmond, please share a toy version of the dataset by adding a code block with the dataframes top 10-20 rows. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If need set all values by first non missing values per groups:

```
df['catH'] = df.groupby('a')['catH'].transform('first')
```

If need replace only missing values by first non missing values per groups:

```
df['catH'] = df['catH'].fillna(df.groupby('a')['catH'].transform('first'))
```

If need replace missing values by previous non missing per groups:

```
df['catH'] = df.groupby('a')['catH'].bfill()
```

Test sample data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
 
print (df.loc[[384,744,724,702]])
     match_id     a    b catH catA
384    757987  1286   84    b    m
744    758340  1286   73    m    t
724    758349  1286   77    m    m
702    758275  1286  267    m    b

df['catH1'] = df.groupby(['a'])['catH'].transform('first')

df['catH2'] = df.groupby(['a'])['catH'].bfill()

df['catH3'] = df['catH'].fillna(df.groupby(['a'])['catH'].transform('first'))

print (df.loc[[384,744,724,702]])
     match_id     a    b catH catA catH1 catH2 catH3
384    757987  1286   84    b    m     b     b     b
744    758340  1286   73    m    t     b     m     m
724    758349  1286   77    m    m     b     m     m
702    758275  1286  267    m    b     b     m     m
```